# How to delay submitting a form in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a bit of a Javascript noob but I need to submit a form using "post" in Javascript to a website, but I am using some conditions in my code and it looks something like this:

```
function submitForm()
{
   if(condition == true)
           {
               //submit the form
           }
           else{
               //do not submit the form
           }
}
```

Is this possible to do? I couldn't find anything online but I thought I might ask here before I try and figure out al alternative.

Might be worth mentioning that this function gets called from a button's onclick in HTML as an event.

Comment: Note in the duplicate I marked that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8664535/519413) is the better approach. Also, you should hook the event to the `submit` event of the `form` element, not the click of the button. This is for accessibility reasons, among many others.

Comment: Please do not edit your question into a brand new one. Instead please ask a [new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).